# How to compare value of element with other siblings with group by function using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have following xml -

```
<Invoices>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>1234</InvoiceNum>
        <BusinessNum>9999</BusinessNum>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>1234</InvoiceNum>
        <BusinessNum>9999</BusinessNum>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>1235</InvoiceNum>
        <BusinessNum>9998</BusinessNum>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice>
        <InvoiceNum>1235</InvoiceNum>
        <BusinessNum>9990</BusinessNum>
    </Invoice>
</Invoices>
```

First I have to group by this XML based on Invoice num and then I have to do mapping only if BusinessNum is same for nodes of InvoiceNum. For ex - InvoiceNum 1234 is allowed as BusinessNum is same in both nodes where as 1235 is not allowed as businessNum are different in both nodes.

I have tried below XSLT -

```
 <xsl:for-each-group select="/Invoices" group-by="Invoice">
       <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::current-group()/BusinessNum[1] = BusinessNum">
</xsl:if>

// Further mapping
```

Above XSLT mapping is not working.
Could you please help me with this mapping using xslt 2.0?

Comment: Your question is about XSLT 1.0 - but `xsl:for-each-group` requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.

Comment: Hello Michael, It was typo error. Please let me know in xslt 2.0

Comment: I still don't understand your question. I*think* you want to group by BusinessNum first, then by InvoiceNum. Bu that's only a guess.

Comment: Hello Michael, No. I have to group by first InvoiceNum and then I have to check in group by result if BusinessNum are same for invoiceNum which I have grouped by.

Comment: Well, that should be easy if you count `distinct-values(current-group()/BusinessNum)`.

Comment: Sorry. Is it XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? Please correct the tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following xsl selects the values of "allowed" `InvoiceNum`s by checking that all the values of `BusinessNum` in each group are the same:

```
<xsl:template match="Invoices">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Invoice" group-by="InvoiceNum">
             <xsl:if test="count(distinct-values(current-group()/BusinessNum))=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>                     
              </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```